# Django filter and update atomicity

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, atomic

When updating filtered records, is there a need for `select_for_update` if you want to make sure that the filtered rows won't get changed by some other process before this `update` is done, or is this filter + update atomicity guaranteed out-of-the-box?

I.e., is this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    Foo.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).update(**kwargs)
```

equivalent to:

```
Foo.objects.filter(id=1).update(**kwargs)
```

?

I'm using Django 1.6.x.

Comment: You **really** should not be using Django 1.6 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You don't need to use the `select_for_update` when everything makes in a single query (your case).

**Longer answer:**

It calls "Dirty reads" and it is covered by the "Read Committed" transaction isolation level which is usually used by default.